# How can I have Xcode Instruments report un-allocated memory as leaked?

Tags: c++, xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm trying to hunt down memory leaks using Xcode instruments (5.0.1) for a C++ project. Consider this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

class Person
{
public:
  int _age;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  Person* pers1 = new Person();
  pers1->_age = 25;
  std::cout << "Pers1 age is " << pers1->_age << std::endl;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000));
  return 0;
}
```

I'm not expecting the "Leaks" instrument to report any leaks, since

> Leaks [...] doesn't know what you're gonna do with your pointers. All it knows is that every block of allocated memory is still referenced somewhere.

as Zneak points out [in his answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3705629/182048). *

However, I'm quite surprised that Allocations doesn't hint at a `Person` object being allocated, and subsequently leaked.

What would I have to do (except for `_pers1 = NULL;`) in order to get Instruments report that this program was leaking? Or is there no leak here at all, and I have misunderstood something regarding the memory allocation model of C++? Doesn't every `new` operator call have to be matched with a `delete` call?

---

*) In the same answer, the claim is being made that

> For a leak to occur, you have to lose the reference you have to allocated memory.

I have no better word for heap memory not being freed by a program that allocates said memory than "leak". So technically what I'm asking about may not be a "leak", but I think it is clear what phenomena I'm thinking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `pers1` variable is still in scope until the end of the main function, so the memory isn't ever going to be reported as leaked. As soon as the memory would leak, the program terminates anyway.

If you wanted to make the memory leak, you could put the first three lines of the body of main in another function, then call that function from main before you call sleep. It should be able to report that the memory leaked, because the program is still running, but the `pers1` variable would no longer be in scope.

Comment: Thanks Gavin! So just to be clear: when the program terminates, the OS will reclaim all memory allocated by my program?

Comment: You are correct. That happens every single OS out there that I am aware of.

Comment: @conciliator Yes, that's correct, so there's no need to free something right before the program terminates, because termination of the program will reclaim all of the memory being used by the app in the first place. Otherwise every time a program crashed we would have horrible memory leaks every single time.

Comment: Thanks guys! I guessed it could be something like that, but didn't know for sure. :)