# Memory leak not detected by Instruments in C

Tags: c, xcode, memory, memory-leaks

My first question is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int *x = (int*)malloc(20*sizeof(int));
    x[0] = 10;
    x[1] = 10;

    sleep(60);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a memory leak above?

Someone may consider this as a repost of this one(though the linked question is from C++ but should be same though): [Why doesn't Xcode + Instrument Leaks detect this leak in simple C++ program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705611/why-doesnt-xcode-instrument-leaks-detect-this-leak-in-simple-c-program), just maybe I didn't understand the answer there, the answer there claims there is no leak in above code, which I find contradictory. Since clearly there is a leak, we don't free memory we allocated.

Another subject is why (also in my case) Leaks instrument doesn't report it.. 
But there is some suggestion in the answer ...

Comment: No, no memory leak. You never lose the reference to the allocated memory.

Comment: @SJuan76: now, this is weird: contrary to what I have learned so far :) So it means we don't need to free the memory we allocate using malloc right? (fine I don't lose the reference but what I have read so far all material said you should free whatever memory you allocate using malloc)

Comment: when the program ends all of its memory space is destroyed and returned to the OS. It does not matter at all if you free it or not.

Comment: Certainly, you did not deallocate all dynamically allocated memory by the end of the program. That is not a "leak", but it could still be regarded as an error by some tools.

Comment: It is still a best practice to free the allocated memory in other layers on the program, but not in main.

Comment: To be more precise, a tool that relies in analyzing the execution of the program (v.g. Valgrind) would interpret it as a memory leak, but one that relies in code analysis might realize that it is a "memory leak" that does not affect the program.

Comment: Let's say from a theoretical point of view: is it a leak or not a leak? (the code in the question)

Comment: A leak tends to be associated with a process that runs for a long time, and "forgets" about memory it allocated.  I don't know if there's an absolute standard definition, and I wouldn't get my knickers in a twist about finding one.

Answer (score 2):

Gone are the days when an operating system would persist heap memory after the requesting process has terminated.  Nowadays, OS kernels are helpful enough to clean up.

Now, what you've shown isn't really a memory leak.  It *might* be picked up as a leak if you did this:

```
int *x = (int*)malloc(20*sizeof(int));
x = NULL;
```

In this case, you've removed your only reference to the new memory.

It also might be picked up as a leak if you put the code into some function other than `main`.

Comment: Your last sentence is more interesting, by suggesting if that code is inside other function it maybe a leak (probably because there will be no more reference to the object) - but still I thought the code is main was a *memory leak* I am really confused :/

Comment: @dmcr_code It kinda depends on the heuristics built into the static code analyser.  I am not familiar with the one you are using.  That is why I keep saying "might".  It's fair to say that your code is a leak because you do not deallocate memory.  But it's also fair to say it's not a leak because the program does not need to deallocate that memory and doesn't leak it in any other way.  Also, your code doesn't do anything, so there's a chance that the `malloc` would be optimized out anyway.

Comment: I am assigning x[0] and x[1] - why malloc would be optimized out?

Comment: @dmcr_code Because you don't do anything with those values.  They don't affect any I/O or anything else in the system.  For all intents and purposes, your program would "do" exactly the same thing if it didn't allocate a bunch of memory.  When I say the `malloc` *could* be optimised away, I also mean the subsequent useless assignments.

Comment: you mean in my program above it maybe that malloc was not used? (program does not call it?)

Comment: @dmcr_code It's possible, but I'm only speculating.  I don't know how that code analyser works.  It might decide that the `malloc` never happened, or it might just decide it's not a leak.  I suggest you throw a whole lot of different scenarios at it and see what happens, if you really want to get an idea of what's going on.  I'm sure you can trust the tool works correctly, but you gave it a fuzzy boundary case and then got hung up about the result not fitting in with your expectations.

Comment: Probably it is not optimized out I also tried with printf. But I will try other scenarios too. Btw. I also used another static analyzer tool inside Xcode and it reported 'potential memory leak' ...   Anyway I was still interested theoretically was it a leak or not, I will experiment more with the tool